# How to get public link for the uploaded file on google cloud storage in local dev server(Google App engine+JAVA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload the image files using gcs client library+java in local google app engine dev server. Images are uploaded successfully and i can see the entries created in local datastore under localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore

How to get the public key for the uploaded images so that i can show images in my application. Example profile pic.

Sample copy of code:

```
 String filePath = Constants.gcsUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/"+ objectName;
 GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory
                .createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
                        .initialRetryDelayMillis(10).retryMaxAttempts(10)
                        .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000).build());
        GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(bucketName, objectName);
        GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                .addUserMetadata("cache-control",
                        "max-age=" + (86400 * 365)).mimeType(mimeType)
                .acl(ACL_PUBLIC_READ).build();
        GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(
                filename, options);
        writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(fileBytes));
        writeChannel.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Images service on the local devserver. For that you need a blobkey:

```
BlobstoreService blobStore = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobStore.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + filename.getBucketName() + "/" + filename.getObjectName())); // blobKey can be persisted
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(image));
```

Resizing also works on the local devserver by appending `=sxxxx`, but you can't get the native image size - on production, appending `=s0` to the url gets the original image, but it doesn't work locally.

Comment: Blobstore? I wanted to use cloud storage. Is there a way I could use cloud storage instead of blobstore. Or else, in local should i only use blobstore and in app engine servers I can go for cloud storage. Currently i am using gcs-client-library. Any advice?

Comment: @Giridhar this is still using cloud storage for storing the files, but the Images service still needed a blobKey. Having taken another look at the documentation, there is now a withGoogleStorageFileName, so I think you could bypass the blobKey and just try `imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But i have one final questions, is this the case for testing/staging/production environments running on google app engine stacks or doing the same will i get the urls like http://storage.googleapis.com/<bucketname>/<filename>

Comment: On production you'll get urls like `http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/<some_big_long_key>` - those URLs are public but not guessable, and they should not change (i.e. subsequent calls to getServingUrl will return the same url) so they can be cached.

Comment: Out of interest, did you end up using the `withGoogleStorageFileName` option? It didn't used to exist, and so I'm now planning to refactor my code to use that method.

Comment: Yes, i had used withGoogleStorageFileName in local, how ever in production/staging/testing the file location where i point to save and public url would be same. So, i would use "withGoogleStorageFileName" only in local dev server